# Performance display of images and WindowsCodecsExt.dll in WPF application

Tags: wpf, image, performance, icc

I found that all Initializing PNG images and work with color profiles takes a huge amount of time (c# WPF application).
For example, a window with 3 Images loaded 3 seconds!
I have run the code through a profiler and found the following.
Calling [DllImport ("WindowsCodecsExt.dll", EntryPoint = "IWICColorTransform_Initialize_Proxy")]
Takes almost 1 second!

Any ideas how to fix this?

VS 2012 Express reinstall. does not help.
Reinstall video driver does not help.
Windows 7 Pro 64Bit

[image]